# Python convert string to datetime but formatting is not very predictable

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timedelta

I'm extract the execution time of a Linux process using Subprocess and `ps`. I'd like to put it in a datetime object, to perform datetime arithmetic. However, I'm a little concerned about the output `ps` returns for the execution time:

```
1-01:12:23    // 1 day, 1 hour, 12 minutes, 23 seconds   
  05:39:03    //        5 hours, 39 minutes, 3 seconds
     15:06    //                 15 minutes, 6 seconds
```

Notice there is no zero padding before the day. And it doesn't include months/years, whereas technically something could run for that long.

Consequently i'm unsure what format string to convert it to a `timedelta` because I don't want it to break if a process has ran for months, or another has only ran for hours.

UPDATE

Mozway has given a very smart answer. However, I'm taking a step back and wondering if I can get the execution time another way. I'm currently using `ps` to get the time, but it means I also have the pid. Is there something else I can do with the pid, to get the execution time in a simpler format?

(Can only use official Python libraries)

UPDATE2

It's actually colons between the hours, mins and seconds.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to convert a period of time to a `datetime` object (i.e. a point in time). It should be `timedelta` object

Comment: @buran I'll edit the question, but same problem still exists.

Comment: there is no such thing as _format string_ for `timedelta` object. Please, check the docs first.

Comment: Can you provide more examples of your output string in case you have more or less units?

Comment: @mozway Yeah, done.

Comment: instead of elapsed time (`etime`) probably you can use start time (`start`) and calculated elapsed time yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)

Here is a suggestion on how to convert from your string:

```
import datetime

s = '1-01-12-23'
out = datetime.timedelta(**dict(zip(['days', 'hours', 'minutes', 'seconds'],
                                map(int, s.split('-')))))
```

Output:

```
datetime.timedelta(days=1, seconds=4343)
```

If you can have more or less units, and assuming the smallest units are present you take advantage of the fact that [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) stops with the smallest iterable, just reverse the inputs:

```
s = '12-23'
units = ['days', 'hours', 'minutes', 'seconds']

out = datetime.timedelta(**dict(zip(reversed(units),
                                map(int, reversed(s.split('-'))))))
```

Output:

```
datetime.timedelta(seconds=743)
```

##### As a function

Using [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) to handle the `1-01:23:45` format

```
import re

def to_timedelta(s):
    units = ['days', 'hours', 'minutes', 'seconds']
    return datetime.timedelta(**dict(zip(reversed(units),
                                         map(int, reversed(re.split('[-:]', s))))))

to_timedelta('1-01:12:23')
# datetime.timedelta(days=1, seconds=4343)

to_timedelta('05:39:03')
# datetime.timedelta(seconds=20343)

to_timedelta('15:06')
# datetime.timedelta(seconds=906)
```

Comment: I've just updated the question as someone asked me to add some more examples. These might affect your answer.

Comment: @intrigued_66 that someone was me, and I already updated my answer ;)

Comment: Your answer is very smart, I'm just wondering if there's another way I can extract the running time which might make parsing easier. Is it only available from `ps` in Linux? (I can't use unofficial Python libraries)

Comment: @intrigued_66 maybe, you would need to update your question with an example of the code in this case

Comment: There's not really any code to show to be honest. I'm simply executing the ps command, getting the pid and execution time. However, I wonder if there's another way to get the execution time (using the pid) in a nicer format.

Comment: Still, show how you run it and collect the data. For instance my `ps` shows me a different output

Comment: I'm calling via subprocess so I have the command as an array like this: `["ps", "-u " + user, "-o user,pid,etime"]`

Comment: Just ran the same `ps` command in terminal and I get the same output as my question. RedHat 7.9

Comment: Well, if you use `check_output` the output is **text**, so you need to process it

Comment: I presume you're implying `ps` is the only interface to access running-time? So we just have to parse this, as per my Q and your A

Comment: I don't know, there might be a python utility for that. Let me dig ;)

Comment: You might be interested in [`psutil`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Forgive me but I've made a HUGE mistake. The format is actually d-hh:mm:ss, as in there are colons between the h, m and s. I had to switch between two machines and manually type the question/couldnt copy-paste. Is this a massive change to your answer? I'll update my question if your solution can still match it.

Comment: Then split with `re.split('[:-]', s)`, see update

Comment: Thanks, gave you some more rep too.

Comment: I don't think it's working correctly. If you run these two: `print(to_timedelta("1-04:26:47").seconds)` and `print(to_timedelta("22:45:01").seconds)` you'll see the second has a larger returned value, but the first has ran for longer according to the string

Comment: @intrigued_66 yes it does, but you need to use `to_timedelta("1-04:26:47").total_seconds()`. `.seconds` doesn't take the days into account ;)

Comment: All good now!..

Comment: instead of parsing elapsed time (`etime`) from the output they probably can use start time (`start`) and calculated elapsed time.